# Unable to understand the return type of the code snippet

Tags: c++, types, return

I am puzzled why this one is right. The return value is reference type `int&`,
but the the `h()` function return a value `int` type in sentence `return x`. So, how does the `int` return change to a `int &`?

This is the code snippet and compiles fine with the C++ compiler.

```
int& h() {
 int q;
 static int x;
 return x;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns a reference to a static `int`. The `x` is initialized the first time the function `h` is called. Use it like this:

```
int& href = h();
++href; // increments the static variable
int& href2 = h(); // another reference to the same static variable
```

The variable `q` should have no effect and I would consider it dubious.

Answer (score 1):

The reference means that you're actually returning effectively the same variable so changing the value of what was returned will directly alter the value of `x` If the code had been writtten:

```
int h()
{
    int q;
    static int x;
    return x;
}
```

(i.e. not be reference) then you'd be returning a *copy* of the value of `x` (although you should to be fair check out [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).) Returning a reference is efficient, however, there are times (multi-threading being an obvious example) where it can be undesirable and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

`int&` is a reference to an int. `x` is an int. Therefore `return x;` from a function that returns an `int&` returns a reference to `x`.

Also:

Returning a reference to a *local* variable is dangerous, because local variables are destroyed when the function exits. By the time you get the reference the thing that it references doesn't exist. This is called a dangling reference and it's like a pointer that doesn't point to anything.

Static variables are not local variables and do not get destroyed when the function exits. Therefore the reference still points to a valid object when you get it.